# How to correctly use std::normal_distribution in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to get random float numbers in the range `[0.0,1.0]`, so most of these numbers should be around `0.5`. Thus I came up with the following function:

```
static std::random_device __randomDevice;
static std::mt19937 __randomGen(__randomDevice());
static std::normal_distribution<float> __normalDistribution(0.5, 1);

// Get a normally distributed float value in the range [0,1].
inline float GetNormDistrFloat()
{
    float val = -1;
    do { val = __normalDistribution(__randomGen); } while(val < 0.0f || val > 1.0f);

    return val;
}
```

However, calling that function 1000 times leads to the following distribution:

```
0.0 - 0.25 : 240 times
0.25 - 0.5 : 262 times
0.5 - 0.75 : 248 times
0.75 - 1.0 : 250 times
```

I was expecting the first and last quarter of the range to show up much fewer than what is shown above. So it seems I am doing something wrong here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try decreasing the standard deviation.

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__normalDistribution`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the heads up, I have changed these names accordingly.

Comment: A Gaussian returns a random number with mean 0.0 and most of the distribution between -3 and +3. To map to 0-1, choose a truncation level and then apply a trivial arithmetical transform.

Comment: Don't do this: `std::mt19937 __randomGen(__randomDevice())`. It's a broken way to seed a Mersenne Twister. [Here's a way to seed it correctly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114066/simple-random-generator), though as I say in the comments there you're better off just using a random library that isn't terrible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer**: do not chop off the tails of the normal distribution.

**Long answer**: The problem is that with a standard deviation of 1 you have most values inside the interval [0,1]. If you take a look at the normal distribution:

[image]

The part you are using is very much at the center and you would need many more samples to detect a difference. Just cutting of values outside your range is absolutely not going to give you a normal distributed sample.

You can see that the cumulative densitiy function is almost linear in the [0,1] interval you are using:

[image]

Pictures generated with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cumulative%20density%20function%28mean%3D0.5,%20standard%20deviation%3D1%29).

At this zoom in the shape of the distribution is almost triangular, and you can [check the output here](http://ideone.com/vVVwJR) for more samples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

static std::random_device __randomDevice;
static std::mt19937 __randomGen(__randomDevice());
static std::normal_distribution<float> __normalDistribution(0.5, 1);

// Get a normally distributed float value in the range [0,1].
inline float GetNormDistrFloat()
{
    float val = -1;
    do { val = __normalDistribution(__randomGen); } 
    while(val < 0.0f || val > 1.0f);

    return val;
}

int main() {
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    int count3=0;
    int count4=0;
    for (int i =0; i< 1000000; i++) {
        float val = GetNormDistrFloat();
        if (val<0.25){ count1++; continue;}
        if (val<0.5){ count2++; continue;}
        if (val<0.75){ count3++; continue;}
        if (val<1){ count4++; continue;}
    }
    std::cout<<count1<<", "<<count2<<", "<<count3<<", "<<count4<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> Success time: 0.1 memory: 16072 signal:0
>
> 241395, 258131, 258275, 242199

**First Option** (suggested by Caleth): use (the) logistic function 1 / (1 + exp(-x)), which has a domain (−∞, +∞) and range [0,1]. This way you actually get the full normal distribution.

**Another option**: Its not as nice mathematically as the one above, but probably faster. You can use a standard normal distribution with mean 0 and deviation 1 and then remap to `[0,1]` from a much larger range such as +/- 4 standard deviations. Now you have the problem that the weight of your integral is not longer 1 but a little less. Its not actually a random variable anymore.

If you want to get a weight of 1, you can distribute the remaining tails (outside of 4 stds) by not rerolling but by getting a uniformly distributed random value from the `[0,1]` interval, this case:

```
val = NormalRand(0,1);
if abs(val) < 4 return val/8 + 0.5
else return UniformRand(0,1)
```

**Another option** (as suggested by interjay): simply decrease the standard deviation.

Comment: Look at his table. His distribution is approximately uniform.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Look at the image. It fits.

Comment: You still misunderstand.  He is showing evidence from a _flat_ distribution (probably uniform).  You show a normal.  Try cutting your data into intervals of 0.25 width, the counts will not be even.   In short, you show him what it _should_ be, you don't help him getting right what he has wrong.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel how about the new data?

Comment: Still wrong.  With a Normal, you should 5% of values outside of (absolute value of) 1.96, 10% outside of 1.64 and so on.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel And how is that at all relevant? The OP only took the range [-0.5,0.5] of standard deviations, so why would you bring up what happens at 1.96?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I added the CNF which shows the linearity at the interval much better.

Comment: I think he used a mean of 0.5 and a standard dev of 1.0, not what you state.

Comment: Agree with linearity of the CNF in that range.  But doesn't your analysis also show all data falling into the four buckets?   Which can't be true for a Normal.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, this is the CNF for mean 0.5 and stdd 1.0.

Comment: Ooops. My bad. I overlooked that he _on purpose_ truncates the distribution.  So that is of course no longer a standard normal....

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yeah, exactly. He is chopping off the tails, so to say :)

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your feedback, but now I am confused. So if I should not chop of the tails on both ends, what else would I need to do in order to receive a number in the range `[0,1]` with the mean of `0.5` and this typical curve shape in the distribution?

Comment: @Matthias chop the tails, if you want/need, but use a smaller deviation, so that your values peak more closely to the mean. (But be aware that, in doing so, you're not using a 'real' normal. Maybe it fits your needs, but it's not technically a normal distribution)

Comment: `normalDistribution(0.5, 0.125);` Try with different stddevs yourself by checking the distribution with wolframalpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=normal+distribution+mean%3D0.5+stddev%3D0.125 Bigger stddev = more numbers at both ends. `normalDistribution(0.5, 0.5/3);` looks nice, too.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all your feedback, works fine now!

Comment: @Beginner Another way to map it is to use (the) logistic function `1 / (1 + exp(-x))`, which has a domain (−∞, +∞) and range [0,1]

Answer (score 4):

It *really* helps to visualize this.  I tend to like R where I can also bring in C++ code easily.  So here is a slightly modified version of your code, generated *standard normals* (ie not truncated) and truncated as you do:

```
#include <random>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> getNormals(int n) {
    std::vector<double> X(n);
    std::mt19937 engine(42);
    std::normal_distribution<> normal(0.0, 1.0);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        X[i] = normal(engine);
    }
    return X;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> getTruncatedNormals(int n) {
    std::vector<double> X(n);
    std::mt19937 engine(42);
    std::normal_distribution<> normal(0.0, 1.0);
    int i=0;
    while (i<n) {
        double x = normal(engine);
        if (x > -0.5 && x < 0.5) {
            X[i++] = x;
        }
    }
    return X;
}


/*** R
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # two plot
x <- getNormals(1000)
hist(x, main="Normal")
z <- getTruncatedNormals(1000)
hist(z, main="Truncated")
par(op)
*/
```

In an R session with the Rcpp package, I can just call `Rcpp::sourceCpp("code.cpp")` on the file and the code compiles, loads the two C++ functions and runs the R part at the end.  I get this chart:
[image]

And even at just 1000 draws, we see the bell curve of the normal, and the near uniform you get when only going 1/2 each side of the mean under a standard deviation of 1.

Long story short: OP knows *how* to create a distribution, even a truncated one, but now needs to figure out *which* distribution he wants.

*Edit:* At n=1e6 we see the curvate of the Normal even for the truncated case:

[image]

Comment: This is nice! I would be courious what would happen to the truncated distribution with a lot more samples? Shouldnt it converge to a triangular shape?

Comment: Some curvature appears with 1e6 draws, see the updated post.